# Module parse failed when using bigint literal in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bigint

I am working on a personal project to try and learn the Angular framework. I'm currently a total newbie with it, but I have manage (I think) to include javascript `bigint` number type correctly in typescript (by targeting the esnext version in the tsconfig.json file) since this works fine :

```
export class Particule {

  public name: String;
  public amount: bigint;
  public cost: bigint;

  constructor(name: String, amount: bigint, cost: bigint)
  {
      this.amount=amount;
      this.name=name;
      this.cost=cost;
  }

  public increment(): void {
      this.amount += BigInt(1); // <<< this line compiles, no problem
  }

  /* ... */

}
```

But if I replace the content of the `increment()` method with : `this.amount += 1n;` i get the following error :

```
ERROR in ./src/app/entities/particule.ts 8:24
Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (8:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     }
|     increment() {
>         this.amount += 1n;
|     }
```

It's not a rellay 'big' problem (see what I did there :D ) since everything works with the `BigInt()` call, but I was wondering if there is a way to use straight up bigint literals in my project !

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Babel/TypeScript should update its compiler to také that info account. Report it as bug to Angular team, Théby Might handle it...

Comment: Actually, what version of `typescript` are you using, @Olivier?

Answer (score 1):

This is because BigInt isn't yet part of the ECMAScript standard, it is a [stage 3 proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-bigint/).

Hence TypeScript support is currently [restricted](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-2/#bigint) to targeting `esnext`.

If you are targeting `esnext`, BigInt literals should work. If you aren't, the error message would be:

> BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ESNext.

Perhaps an old version of `typescript` is in use?

Comment: `tsc -v --> Version 3.4.5` ! What is strange is that the call to `BigInt()` seems to work fine, but the literals don't !

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer some changes in the angular project are needed:

in package.json "typescript": "4.3.5" or greater

in tsconfig.json update

```
"module": "esnext", 
"lib": ["ESNext","dom"]
"target": "esnext"
```