# Bigint, Angular and HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, angular-httpclient, bigint

I'm currently coming from ASP.Net MVC, trying to build an Angular application for my controller endpoints. My model, however; contains a ulong. This was fine, I presumed, as the JSON sent through the controller had this value correctly set. However; once it arrived in Angular, the value had been corrupted, and was ~50 off from what it should have been.

Later, I found this was due to Javascript's limitations on the size of a number. The weird thing was, all my models in Angular were set to bigints, not numbers.

It's quite possible that the JSON deserializer in Angular is treating these ulongs as numbers, not bigints, which would cause this corruption through JavaScript's safe/unsafe size constraints. However, bigint has been in the specification for a few years by now, and I was wondering if there was any way around this?

I've looked at last StackOverflow answers for this problem, but many of them are from *before* bigint was introduced as a datatype officially.

For context, this is what I'm using in Angular to get my user data:

```js
  private currentUserSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  private init = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private cookieService: CookieService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  loadUserConfig() {
    this.http.get(API_URL + '/users/@me').subscribe((data) => {
      this.currentUserSubject.next(data);
    }, (error) => {
      this.currentUserSubject.error(null);
      this.handleError(error);
    });
  }

  getUserProfile(reinit: boolean = false): Observable<AppUser> {
    if (reinit || ( !this.init && this.isLoggedIn())) {
      this.init = true;
      this.loadUserConfig();
    }
    return this.currentUser$;
  }
```

Where AppUser is a model that contains another model, which has the bigint value in question. IE:

```js
export interface Guild {
  id: bigint;
}

export interface AppUser {
  adminGuilds: Guild[];
}
```

Raw sent data:

```json
{"adminGuilds":[{"id":613441321751019550}]}
```

I realise that I could send them across as strings, but sending them as ulongs and storing them as bigints is a much more elegant solution, in my opinion, than having to create seperate viewmodels that are identical to their model counterpart but with strings instead of ulongs.

-Ferox

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70447720/238704) might be relevant.

Comment: I already have typescript updated with Angular to support bigints, it's just that the JSON deserializer that is used in the HttpContext doesn't convert it to a bigint, rather keeping it as a number, even if the model states that it's meant to be serialized to a bigint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BigInt** in JS/TS is created by appending *n* to the end of an integer literal. Though you are using bigint type to represent your large numbers they are still being  treated as numbers and hence you see loss of data in numbers.

Consider this:

```
interface Guild {
  id: bigint;
}

 interface AppUser {
  adminGuilds: Guild[];
}

const a: AppUser = {"adminGuilds":[{"id":613441321751019550}]};
```

Above will not compile in TS as the number 613441321751019550 is not a bignint but a number (as there is no n at the end. You will get the below error:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'bigint'.

```
const a: AppUser = {"adminGuilds":[{"id":613441321751019550n}]};
```

It will compile fine and if you log `alert(a.adminGuilds[0].id)` you will not get data loss.

What you will need to do is add *n* at the end of numbers in your API response to be properly represented as bigint in JS/TS.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I'm really new to typescript in general, so apologies for the newb question haha. Do you know of any way to add the "n" to the end of the JSON returned by the ASP.NET API Controllers? It's not really part of the spec, but hopefully there's some wizardry in C# that can make this happen? I know ASP.Net uses System.Text.Json to serialize, so perhaps there's a way, either through this or in Angular before it is deserialized,  to ensure the data is correctly retained?

Comment: Marking as answer since it was the reason that the bigint wasn't being converted correctly to my knowledge, however routing and other components for us would've needed to be rewritten. I made a janky ulong converter in ASP.Net to append the "n" to what our MVC sends, but it was more of a bodge than it was worth :P